# RegionMember not returning analytical result

Tags: graphics, functions, function-construction, symbolic, regions

From this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164420/make-mathematica-create-equations-and-put-them-into-nsolve) I'm using a function by *kglr* to find the inequality constraints for a shape.

The function is this

```
constraints[shapes__] := 
 And[## & @@ (Not /@ 
      Through[(RegionMember[RegionIntersection@##] & @@@ 
          Subsets[{shapes}, {2}])@#]), 
   RegionMember[RegionUnion @@ (RegionBoundary /@ {shapes})]@#] &
```

This works great if I have a shape with just integers. The inequalities is exactly what I would expect

```
constraints[Cuboid[{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}]][{x, y, z}]
```

Returns

```
(x | y | z) \[Element] Reals && ((-1 + z == 0 && -1 + y >= 0 && 3 - x - y >= 0 &&  2 - x <= 1) || (-1 + z == 0 &&   2 - y >= 0 && -3 + x + y >= 0 && -1 + x <= 1) || (-1 + x == 0 && -1 + y >= 0 && -y + z >= 0 && -1 + z <= 1) || (-1 + x == 0 && 2 - y >= 0 && y - z >= 0 && 2 - z <= 1) || (-2 + y == 0 && -1 + x >= 0 && -x + z >=  && -1 + z <= 1) || (-2 + y == 0 && 2 - x >= 0 && x - z >= 0 &&  2 - z <= 1) || (-2 + x == 0 && 2 - y >= 0 && -3 + y + z >= 0 && -1 + z <= 1) || (-2 + x == 0 && -1 + y >= 0 && 3 - y - z >= 0 &&  2 - z <= 1) || (-1 + y == 0 &&  2 - x >= 0 && -3 + x + z >= 0 && -1 + z <= 1) || (-1 + y == 0 && -1 + x >= 0 && 3 - x - z >= 0 &&   2 - z <= 1) || (-2 + z == 0 && -1 + y >= 0 && x - y >= 0 && -1 + x <= 1) || (-2 + z == 0 && 2 - y >= 0 && -x + y >= 0 && 2 - x <= 1))
```

Which is great. However, if within the shape definition there a non-integer value, the function will not return an analytical result, i.e.

```
 constraints[Cuboid[{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1.5}]][{x, y, z}]
```

will not work. Note, that the second vector in `Cuboid` has a `1.5`. I cannot find out what section of the function is causing the problem & how I might solve it. At the moment I manually go through and amend the inequalities - this is not ideal.

Comment: As a workaround, you may use rational numbers: `constraints[Cuboid[{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 3/2}]][{x, y, z}]` works fine. Apparently, `RegionMember` assumes that there is no reasonable chance to return a analytic function if there are floating point number present (which is, well, wrong). But it is actually very desirable that `RegionMember` is overly conservative: This way it does not waste precious time building the function in case of too complicated expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that with approximate numbers (e.g. `1.5`), approximate methods are invoked, namely in this case, the region is discretized:

```
First@Head@constraints[Cuboid[{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1.5}]][{x, y, z}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
% // InputForm
(*
MeshRegion[
 {{2., 1., 1.}, {2., 2., 1.}, {1., 2., 1.}, {1., 1., 1.}, {1., 2., 1.5},
  {1., 1., 1.5}, {2., 2., 1.5}, {2., 1., 1.5}},
 {Polygon[{{1, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6}, {3, 7, 5}, {2, 8, 7}, {1, 6, 8}, {6, 7, 8},
   {3, 1, 2}, {5, 4, 3}, {7, 3, 2}, {8, 2, 1}, {6, 1, 4}, {7, 6, 5}}]}]
*)
```

Numerical methods are used to compute the `RegionMemberFunction` for a `MeshRegion`, so a symbolic formula is not produced.

With exact input, as [Henrik suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166627/regionmember-not-returning-analytical-result#comment440065_166627), exact methods are used and if feasible, an exact symbolic description of the region will be produced.